# Изменение стиля окна WPF

Tags: wpf, .net

Как создать единый стиль окна разрабатываемого приложения для всех версий ОС одинаковое?

Просмотрел различные статьи, но все варианты не подходят, тк там утрачивается возможность расширять окно и переносить его по экрану.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как создать кастомный стиль окна WPF не потеряв весь основной функционал, и иметь возможность переносить его и менять размер?

Comment: Могу посоветовать [видео уроки](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vjldip84CXQ&list=PLrW43fNmjaQVYF4zgsD0oL9Iv6u23PI6M), которые мне советовали в своё время. Там автор рассматривает процесс создания кастомного окна с функциями стандартного окна. Единственный минус - уроки на английском.

Comment: @EgorTrutnev не имеет значения английский или русский) спасибо, буду знакомиться с предложенным видео)

Но надеюсь найдутся гуру, которые смогут предложить свои варианты.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сложного:

```
    <Style TargetType="Window">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray"/>
        <Setter Property="Title" Value="My custom window"/>
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="5" CaptionHeight="30" GlassFrameThickness="0" CornerRadius="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Window">
                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent">

                            <!-- Title bar -->
                            <Border Background="White" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid>
                                    <!-- Window title -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>

                                    <!-- Window control buttons stack -->
                                    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                        <!-- Close button, for example -->
                                        <Button Width="40" Height="30" Background="White" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" Click="Button_Click">
                                            <Path Data="M0,0 L20,20 M0,20 L20,0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                                        </Button>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>

                            <!-- Window content -->
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="0,30,0,0"/>
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Style>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Примечания

Значит, полагаю, вы в этой теме новичок (раз в коменты кинули курсы вам) и вам не мешало бы всё "разложить по полочкам".

Значит, поскольку вам нужен одинаковый вид окна на разных версиях Windows, без переопределения фрейма тут не обойтись. Можно его вообще убрать и нарисовать свой (установить `WindowStyle` в `None`), но мы воспользуемся более грамотным решением: используем специальный для этого класс - `WindowChrome` при этом не меняя `WindowStyle` (хотя это без разницы, просто так сохраняются стандартные анимации сворачивания/разворачивания Windows).

За ширину границы изменения размера окна отмечает `WindowChrome.ResizeBorderThickness`. `GlassFrameThickness` можно установить в -1 для включения стандартной тени окна, но тогда на системах Windows 10 где ppi выше 130 будет сильно наблюдаться эффект искажения текста - не советую.

`CaptionHeight` - высотка заголовка окна, т.е. области, за которую можно "потащить окно".

Кнопочки сами нарисуете.

Вообще, почитайте [это](https://habrahabr.ru/post/158561/), а так же можете в мой профиль зайти - там много тем с переопределением шаблонов окон.

Comment: спасибо большое!
С темой разобрался, но забыл отблагодарить(
Также, для тех кто будет реализовывать подобное на версии .Net 4.0 и ниже, нужно установить дополнительную библиотеку.

Comment: Да. Т.к. в .NET 4.0 нет `System.Windows.Shell` namespace. Придётся эту сборку подключать отдельно и "таскать за собой". На Windows XP где вообще нет dwm это будет бесполезно.